# How to insert CSS button in HTML content?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert a button on my emails report and this is the HTML code:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/userdata123/www/htmlblocks-images/600/600809/600809_5441949_63b6c312ceb60.png" alt="" width="201" height="197" /><hr /></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><br /> <span style="font-size: 10pt;">Congratulations <strong>[{Candidate (Name / Surname)(63452141)}]</strong> we have receive your booking request for <strong>[{IADC(103917877)}][{IADC 21% TAX(104978681)}][{IWCF(104978693)}][{IWCF 21% TAX(104978397)}]</strong> course in english and API units at <strong>[{Choose your location(103915792)}].</strong></span></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><br /> <br /> <span style="font-size: 10pt;">The date you choose for your course is the [{Courses start on Mondays - Select your Week(63452156)}] </span><br /> <br /> </div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"> Please follow the link for our joining instructions</span><br /> <br /><hr />
<p><br /> <br /> </p>
</div>
<br /> <br /> <br />
```

and this is the CSS button I created:

```
.BUTTON_SPY {
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 40px;
   font-weight: 100;
   padding: 40px;
   background-color: rgba(61, 246, 169, 0.68);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0 #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0 #000000;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0 #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
}

.BUTTON_SPY:hover {
   background: #00B2C7;
   border: solid #FFFFFF 1px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

How can I join the two together? Fit the CSS button in HTML code line?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you just looking for the `<style>` element to add CSS to an HTML document?

Comment: Where do you want the button to be?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a button. At first, create a  element. DOCTYPE html>   Styling Buttons   Submit  
2.Style your button. So, it is time to apply styles to your button.